# iterate on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I have two tables where one is a container and the other are items. 
I want to find an item then find all containers that contain that specific item.
I have the query but it will find only one container. It's all XML which makes it a little complicated.

(I search in table1 inside xml then when I find what I want I get the guid from the col and then search in table12 xml using the guid I found in table1 )

table1

```
Guid |    Name   |   t1XML
 1          n1       file1
 2          n2       file2
```

table2

```
Guid   |    Name   |   t2XML
  7          n7        cont7
  9          n9        cont9
```

** guids are normal guids (36 char)

this is what I have

```
DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(max)=N'context' 
SELECT t1.Name as itemName, t1.Guid, t2.Name
FROM table1 AS t1 
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.t2XML.query('/t/n').value('.', 'VARCHAR(36)')= CAST(t1.Guid as varchar(36))
WHERE t1.t1XML.exist(N'/t/am[text()[1]=sql:variable("@searchFor")]')=1 order by t2.Name
```

so what I want is, when I find an item from t1 which has 'context', I want the join to iterate to t2 and find all containers that has this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out doing this

```
DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(max)=N'context'  
SELECT DISTINCT t2.Name , t2.Guid , filtered.Name 
FROM table2 AS t2
JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name, lower(t1.Guid) as t1GUid
   FROM table1 AS t1
   WHERE t1.t1XML.exist(N'/t/am[text()[1]=sql:variable("@searchFor")]')=1 
) AS filtered
ON t2.t2XML.exist(N'/t/n[text()[1]=sql:column("filtered.t1Guid")]')=1
```